# Deploying Apache FOP to Wildfly

Tags: apache, wildfly, apache-fop, jboss-modules

I have a simple MDB that does FO to PDF transformations using Apache FOP. Initially I tried to include FOP as a library in my ear but that failed with class loading error.

From what I can understand, 3rd party libraries need to be created as modules in JBoss/Wildfly.

I then tried to create a wildfly module for fop and am now getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry
```

The code giving the error is as follows:

```
    try {
        fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File("fopconf.xml"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
```

I have also followed the information from this link https://developer.jboss.org/thread/204749?start=0&tstart=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They can definitely be included in your deployment. You'd only make it a module if you want to share it across many deployments. What does your `module.xml` look like?

Comment: I managed to get it to deploy as part of the deployment and its working thanks!